# Can't vertically center my logo

Tags: css

On [my page](http://goo.gl/cTFN8i) the top left logo isn't centered. Here's my code:

```
.header_col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #009240;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.header_col1 a {    /* my logo */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Yet according to articles I've read this technique should work. Why not in this case? I don't want to use absolute positioning because the green area around the logo descreases in size in smaller resolutions and logo must do so too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

Apply `display: table-cell` to the `a` element wrapping your image and inherit the width and height from the `.header-col1` ancestor block.

You can then use `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` to get the alignment that you want.  Add some left-right padding if you need some white space at the left and right edges.

Finally, to get the image to act responsively, set `width: 100%` and use `vertical-align: top` to take care of the white-space-below-the-baseline issue.

```css
.header_col1, .header_col2 {
  height: 110px;
}
.header_col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: #009240 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.header_col1 a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 0 10px; /* optional if you need left/right whitespace */
}
.header_col1 a img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_col1">
  <a id="logo" href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/262x78">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Works!! Thx Marc. Since you're clearly very skilful I'd like to ask you something that I often wonder: don't you think that CSS has some fundamental awkwardness in it as a web layout system, considering the difficulty of achieving something as simple as centering a logo in a rectangle?

Comment: @drake035 Compared to word processing or desktop publishing applications, web browsers are fairly primitive layout engines and CSS works pretty well given the constraints of the browser, that is, the browser has to set a layout based (more or less) on a one-pass look at the content.  In short, I do agree that CSS can be awkward at times, but compared to ten years ago, the technology has come a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the display table magic trick :-)

```
 .header_col1 {
   display:table;

}
.header_col1 a {    /* my logo */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Works but now the logo image becomes size-fixed, forcing green element to maintain enough size, whereas I need it to shrink when header bar total width decreases on smaller resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would center it with transforms.

```
.header_col1 a {    /* my logo */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    padding: .5em;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

EDIT: Added `padding: .5em;` to give the logo some breathing room on smaller screens, when the container starts to shrink.

Comment: Works but logo size becomes invariant, and I need the logo to shrink when green container shrinks.

Comment: @drake035 The logo should still shrink when the container shrinks. It works fine for me in Chrome inspector

Comment: If you'd like to give the logo more breathing room, add `padding: .5em;` to the ruleset above when the container starts to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a line-height equal to the height for the `.header_col1` for this technique to work:

```
.header_col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #009240;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 110px;
}
.header_col1 a {    /* my logo */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

...and the img needs to be a block-element:

```
.header_col1 a img {
    display: block;
}
```

*Edit:*
Add this to retain the flexible sizing:

```
.header_col1 a {
    width: 100%;
}
.header_col1 a img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Just tried, still doesn't work. The logo image remains on top of the green container.

Comment: Works now but same as other answers: the logo size is not fixed, whereas I need it to shrink as header bar width decreases.

Comment: @drake035 so same place that you set `.header_col1, .header_col2 {height: 70px;}` just add `line-height: 70px;`

Comment: The only way the line-height technique works is with fixed heights... but since you are already defining the `.header_col1` with a fixed height (which is then adjusted in a media query), I don't see how that is problematic. If the fixed height is temporary, and not an option for the final solution, then any of the other solutions suggested can solve the problem too, they are just entirely different techniques (some of which you should stay away from for a few years if you want to support older browsers)

Answer (score 0):

The new hotness would be this;

```
.header_col1 {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;

}
.header_col1 a {    /* my logo */
    margin: auto;
}
```

Note: as time goes by, the vendor prefixes `-webkit- -moz- ms-` will be not nessacery.

here is a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/w4m50ybd/1/

Bonus: making the image resize to the container is a different question.. however the answer to that is `width: 100%; height: auto;` in the most simple case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.header_col1:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.header_col1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/usmanarshad87/pen/rVWYNY)

Answer (score 0):

I have added `line-height` to the anchor tag.

[image]

```
  header_col1 a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the table display to align a tag vertically and horizontally. This way is the easiest way to align an element. I did test on your page, it worked perfectly.

```
.header_col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background: #009240;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
}
.header_col1 a {    /* my logo */
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

or another way is to use padding to center your element.

```
.header_col1 a {
  padding: 16px 0px;
}
```

To avoid other headache while changing the size of your navigation in other devices and screen resolution, I recommend the first solution.